# Error messages generated in 'Customize Your Site'

Tags: errors, theme-customizer

I've recently installed WordPress locally on my Mac. Unfortunately though, when I click on Customize Your Site, the loading circle just keeps spinning and spinning. This is the case in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.

To resolve the problem, so far I have:

1. Reinstalled WordPress, with fresh MySQL database and all;
2. Checked that the problem persists in all browsers;
3. Flushed all caches and cookies;
4. Enabled `SCRIPT_DEBUG` (should I disable this now, by the way?);
5. Performed diagnostics using the error consoles on all three browsers.

Below are the error codes that were generated on each browser:

**Safari**: `[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 (Precondition Failed) (localhost, line 0)`

**Firefox**: `downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "dashicons" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://localhost/wp-includes/fonts/dashicons.eot`

**Chrome**: `GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&ver=4.3.1 net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED`

I can provide screenshots of these error messages if necessary.

Could my problem have something to do with the fact that I've installed it locally?

Comment: About FireFox You get this error if you run out of memory when loading the fontfile or if there is something wrong with the layout (contents) of the fontfile. This is a protection against bad or malicious font files. It is probably possible to disable the sanitizer by setting the pref gfx.downloadable_fonts.sanitize to false in about:config but then you are no longer protected. Use at your own risk. Do not blame Mozilla if you are infected with malware.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How do I access `about:config`?

Comment: if you want you just don't see this error in your browser , do you really need this ? or you need solve error in users browsers ??

Comment: i would advice disactivating plugins and seeing if the errors persist. Also it would be nice if you stated which software you are using for local development !